# Select a shape in a set of shape on panel java

Tags: java, graphics

I draw multiple shapes on a panel, for example, I have a rectangle, a square and a triangle.

Now I want to move one of these shape **at a time**. This means when I choose to move the rectangle, if it collapse with the square, the square stays still and the rectangle still moving.

Can someone give me a tip to do it? I stuck quite a bit. I tried to put in a HashMap, if a shape is moving, boolean true, the rest will be false.

But I wasn't successful...

Comment: Post your code. Debugging code is hard without your code.

Comment: I want to know about the idea, I don't want to post a code. Because all the ideas that I can think of are fail... All of them can't solve the problem. These shapes extends from an abstract class. So I really need an idea.

Comment: Just google for custom painting in java. It will show you tutorials for beginners. If you manage to write code but have a specific question then come back and edit your question.